# How can I prevent OSX upgrade messing up my apache ant install

Tags: upgrade, java

I'm a developer that uses Apache Ant as part of my build environment, but every time I upgrade my Mac to a new version of the OS (such as Yosemite to El Capitan) it breaks the ant install it there a way I can prevent this.

Comment: How does it break the install? ant etc should not be in a directory that Apple changes

Comment: Well it is and now doesnt exist at all. I think previously it was part of the Apple OS but I always had to copy over some custom jars after an upgrade, but with the upgrade to El Capitan it doesnt seem to exist at all

Comment: Where exactly is it? not here on Yosemite

Comment: hmm I thought it was in /usr/bin - perhaps it was removed earlier than El Capitan and I manually installed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS X used to come with a version of Apache ant, but not since OS X 10.9.

I think that previously I must have installed into `/usr/bin` directly from the apache site but that is a bad idea because on upgrade anything Apple doesn't recognise in `/usr/bin` is removed (although a copy is moved to `/Library/SystemMigration/History/Migratio**********/QuarantineRoot`).

Instead I should have installed into `/usr/local`

I did this using [homebrew](http://brew.sh), installation of homebrew and then ant with homebrew was easy and I did not have to manually setup any paths, however note if you need to install custom jars they need to be put into (i.e `/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.6/libexec/lib`) libexec/lib which is non-standard, there is no libexec folder in the standard version of ant. Other than I have had no other issues with the homebrew version of ant.